# Why are registers being turned on to 1 before reset/on button is hit on FPGA?

Tags: fpga, verilog, reset, cyclone

I am writing a really simple program on Verilog for my FPGA to have an LED blink once a button is pushed. Here is the code I have written:

```
module hello_world(
   input ron,           //reset button (ron = reset/on) 
   input clk,           //clk, on board clk is 25 MHz
   output reg led1,     //led to blink
   output reg start);   //problematic signal

reg [22:0] led;
always @(posedge clk) begin 
    if(!ron) begin
        led <= 0;
        start <= 1;
    end

    if(start) begin
        led <= led + 23'b00000000000000000000001;
        led1 <= led[22];
    end
end


endmodule
```

I know there are probably cleaner ways of doing this, but I'm just doing this way, and there is a really weird problem that is occurring. The 'start' register is being set to 1 before I even hit the 'ron' button (reset/on button) and I have no clue why. This problem is happening with any register that I assign 1 to in the if statement.

I tried simulating it in ModelSim, and it seems to run fine, but on the FPGA board (Polmaddie7) it assigns start to 1 before the button is hit.

I would appreciate any help on this please. If I have left any information out that would be helpful to understanding/answering this, please let me know.

Comment: Your button may be an active-low type. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774540/vhdl-connect-switch-and-led/50775478#50775478)

Comment: Also, some FPGAs have flip-flops are automatically globally reset at start-up, whether your code explicitly describes this behavior or not.

Comment: @Oldfart It is an active low pin, that's why I have !ron in the if statement to account for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities (at least)

- Your FPGA has an automatic global reset at start up. Since your code resets `led` to 0 and `start` to 1, these are the values they will get when the global reset is applied.
- Your FPGA doesn't have an automatic global reset. In that case, the initial value of `led` and `start` are unpredictable. They just happen to be coming up as 0 and 1 respectively as a matter of chance (and the operating temperature, timing of the power supply ramp up, etc.)

If you want to know what value your `start` signal will have at power up (for example, you want it to be 0 until the `ron` signal goes low), then you should code it to reset to 0, and implement a global reset, or choose an FPGA that automatically performs global reset. In this case you need to code the reset behavior of `start` as going to 0, and use `ron` as an ordinary signal (not routed on the dedicated reset inputs of the flip-flops) that causes a state transition of `start` from low to high.

Comment: What do you mean by dedicated reset routing resources, when specifying the pin for the  `ron` I just assigned it to a button? Can you elaborate on what you mean by using `ron` as an ordinary signal causing a transition?

Comment: @Lokwill, that wasn't really what I should have said. I've corrected the answer post.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still confused. I am relatively new to the FPGA world. I don't understand how led is 0 and start is 1 if my code says that this should only happen when `!ron` occurs.

Comment: @Lokwill, if the FPGA has automatic global reset, it will automatically assert `!ron` at start-up (and in a way that the clock doesn't matter), regardless of what your code says. There might be a way to disable this, but how to do it would depend on exactly which FPGA you're using.

Comment: However if you disable global reset, then what state `start` comes up in is unpredictable. It might always be 1, might always be 0, might sometimes be 1 and sometimes 0, etc. You're much better off using global reset and explicitly choosing which way your signals come up.

Comment: So how would I have it not assert `!ron`? You mentioned using it as an ordinary signal, but I thought that's what I'm doing now.

Comment: Just what I said in my answer: "In this case you need to code the reset behavior of start as going to 0, and use ron as an ordinary signal". You can either use an `initial` block, or an `if(greset) begin ... end else begin ... end` structure in your code to implement the reset behavior.

Comment: The synthesis tool may also be doing bubble pushing. If it infers that you want the register to reset to 1 (based on the code describing a synchronous reset), it can add inverters to the data in and data out of the storage register(s). That way the FPGA on configure can (if supported) simply set all registers to zero, and the inverter will take care of it appering as 1 to the rest of the circuit.

Comment: In Altera FPGAs, global reset happens at start up and it automatically resets to the values you either specified as initial values or the values given in the reset block. If both mismatch, synthesiser throws a warning as well :)

Answer (score 1):

**my answer**

Quartus has an option named "power-Up don't care" enabled by default.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/17.0/mapIdTopics/mwh1465427440242.htm

My guess is quartus sees that it will be reset at 1, and so start it as 1

**notes on the code**

- In general it is a good idea to have a power up reset logic to avoid this kind of problem. Simply because this is what we usually do in simu, so to simply make life easier for a lot of things.
- I have seen cases where it is preferable to disable the "power-Up don't care" to about don't cares in synthesys.